# GRASS r.out.mat memory issues

Tags: python, grass-gis

we have built a model with pythn/GRASS that calls the r.out.mat module. The area is quite large 25,000x25,000 cells. The machine we are running it on is Windows 7 machine with 16GB of RAM.

After a while the script aborts complaining about an out of memory issues. Now, I would not have expected to have such issues with so much RAM even though the manual page for r.out.mat does say that the module loads the whole map into RAM so it requires a huge amount of RAM. Any idea on how we can optimise the script avoid such problems? If this is a limitation of the module, I was wondering whether r.out.mat could be used to read the map area in patches, dump out the results in single files and then some other module patches all the r.out.mat results together. Any suggestions on how we can overcome this issue?

Thanks
Antonio

Comment: Which GRASS version do you use?